# Submitting an app to AppStore

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

In App Store Review Guidelines there is one thing:

```
Apps should have all included URLs fully functional when you submit it for review, such as support and privacy policy URLs
```

But what should I do, if I don't have any website which provides following information - support link and privacy policy?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an app store and not directly programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence to me reads like *Apps should have all, **if any** included URLs fully functional (...)*. It does not sound like such URLs are required for the app to be accepted.

Comment: So, I may leave them empty? No email:blablabla@gmail.com links?

Comment: Again, to me it *sounds* that way. I'm not 100% percent sure of it.